# Blazor Server available as localhost, but not within local area network. What am i missing?

Tags: blazor, web-development-server

sorry if this is maybe bit of an unspecific question, but i am searching for some kind of instruction since a while and i did not find any good one.

I am creating a web-UI with blazor server and it's running without problems when i access the server on the same device via localhost.

Yesterday, i wanted to run the server on one computer and access the application with another computer in the local area network, which didn't work.

What i already did:

-Turned off the firewall for the server PC

-Used fixed IP on launchSettings.json, instead of localhost:PORT

-pinged server computer to see if the issue is network related. Pinging was successful.

I thought this is really trivial when it is already working on localhost, but it's apparently not. Would be happy if someone could help me out here.

Comment: IIS Express is "Express" by design it is not for this kind of job... 
But, but Always there is a but...  
in your project/solution folder there should be ".vs" folder holds configuration

in {project folder}/.vs/config/applicationhost.config
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:YOUR-APP-PORT:YOUR-COMP-IP" />

ACL Rule
etsh http add urlacl url=http://YOUR-COMP-IP:YOUR-APP-PORT/ user=everyone

Answer (score 2):

You'd think this would be easier, no?  Your server is only listening on `localhost` and there are several ways to configure this.  The challenge, IMO, is finding out which configuration your server is using.

Here is an article that I found helpful to demystify ASP.NET Core URLS: https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/

The easiest approach for local testing (but not suitable for prod deployment) is to configure the web host builder in your Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                // Change here: call UseUrls() with wildcard hostnames
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5003", "https://*:5004");
            });
}
```

Once you get your server working (ie, you can access your server from your dev machine via `http://127.0.0.1:5003`), then you can choose the best configuration option (`UseUrls()`, environment vars, or command line). Side note: there may be some additional steps to get an HTTPS URL to work, ie, you need to have a trusted (dev) cert.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that. The most straightforward approach without changing anything in your code or computer settings is using a third-party extension for visual studio, [Conveyor by Keyoti](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti).
After installing it, restart your visual studio. You can activate it in "Tool -> Conveyor - allow remote access to the development web server." In the new window, select "Remote URL IP address" based on your current IP in your network. Then you can access your project with the given IP and port on any local machine. You can read its documentation for more information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is the correct answer. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Edit: If you have a VS version not in range from 14.0-17.0, you can use that link to install a version of Keyoti for later versions of VS: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti2022.